# template argument deduction for const argument

Tags: c++, templates

Suppose we have

```
template <typename T>
void foo(T a)
{
    a = 10;
}

int main()
{
    const int a = 5;
    foo(a);
}
```

Why T is deduced as int and not const int, why should I can modify a in function?
How deduction works in this case?

[Here's a working sample.](http://ideone.com/JuHuiG)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why T is deduced as int and not const int, why should I can modify a
>   in function?

Because you are passing by value and receiving by value (not reference). According to language grammar such deduction would always result in priority to non-const over `const`.
For better understanding try below C++11 code and print the `typeid`:

```
const int a = 5;  // `a` typeid is `const int`
auto b = a;    // `b` typeid is `int`
```

> How deduction works in this case?

If you want `a` to be non modifiable and respect the `const`ness of the object passed then receive by reference in the function. i.e.

```
template<typename T>
void foo (T& a) 
{
  a = 10; // this will result in error if a `const int`
}
```

[Note: Passing a literal wouldn't [never work](http://ideone.com/U2AIYv) with above signature.]

Comment: Actually, passing a literal wouldn't even reach the call - the literal's type is `int`, so it would deduce to `int&` and fail bind the literal to it.

Answer (score 6):

Why should the fact that the object outside the function is `const` matter to the internals of the function? It is getting it's own copy of the object, so it can choose for itself whether to treat that copy as `const` or not. Modifying `a` inside the function will not affect the object outside. This is the reason that top-level cv-qualifiers are ignored for type deduction.

If you want the parameter to be `const`, you need to ask for it.

Comment: "Why should the fact that the object outside the function is const matter to the internals of the function?": This question makes the OP look dumb and is not helpful at all; pedagogically, it may even lead him into a wrong assumption about this being axiomatic. He might be coming from Java, C# or maybe Python, in which there are different calling conventions.

Comment: @phresnel Why does it make them look dumb? I think it's a helpful question because it gets the asker to think about something that they might not otherwise have done. I'm not assuming that they understand how objects are passed in C++, so I explain that in the next sentence.

Comment: It think it makes them look dumb because you say it like it's a natural given fact, where it really isn't. It just happens to be a fact in C++, which, of course, this question is about. But given that the OP might come from another language where it isn't natural, that rhethorical question at the beginning seems superfluous and judgemental (of course that's just my opinion).